# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el ultimo id de una fila insertada.?

Tags: php

Después de insertar un vehículo en la tabla vehiculo quiero obtener el id de ese vehículo recién insertado para utilizarlo como clave foránea en la tabla imagenesVehiculos.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora pero no me funciona.

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");

    $conexion       = conectar();
    $fkMarca        = $_POST["fkMarca"];
    $fkModelo       = $_POST["fkModelo"];
    $color          = $_POST["color"];
    $anio           = $_POST["anio"];
    $cilindraje     = $_POST["cilindraje"];
    $fkTransmision  = $_POST["fkTransmision"];
    $fkCombustible  = $_POST["fkCombustible"];
    $fkTipo         = $_POST["fkTipo"];
    $precioVenta    = $_POST["precioVenta"];
    $imagen         = $_POST["imagen"];
    $ultimoId = 0;

// VARIABLE PARA RECUPERAR EL SERVIDOR Y EL PUERTO


// Registrar en la tabla vehiculo
    $sql    = "INSERT INTO vehiculo (fkMarca, fkModelo, color, anio, 
cilindraje, fkTransmision, fkCombustible, fkTipo, precioVenta, 
fechaRegistro) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";
    $stmt   = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("iisiiiiid",$fkMarca, $fkModelo, $color, $anio, 
$cilindraje, $fkTransmision, $fkCombustible, $fkTipo, $precioVenta);

// nombre de la imagen.
    $nImagen = uniqid($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], true);
    $nombreImagen = md5($nImagen);


// obtener Ultimo id
    $idUltimo = $stmt->insert_id;

// generar archivo bitmap
    $lastId         = $ultimoId; // último id insertado
    $path           = "imgCarr/$nombreImagen.jpg";
    $url            = "http://localhost:9001/appVehiculos/$path";
    //$bytesArchivo   = file_get_contents($path);
    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));

    $ruta = "imgCarr"."/".$nombreImagen;

// registar en la tabla imagenVehiculo
    $sql2   = "INSERT INTO imagenesvehiculo (imagen, fkVehiculo) VALUES (?, 
?)";
    $stmt2  = $conexion->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->bind_param("si", $nombreImagen, $idUltimo);


// validar si se registró en las tablas
    if($stmt->execute() && $stmt2->execute()){
        echo 'registra';
        echo $idUltimo;
    }else{
        echo 'noRegistra';
        echo $idUltimo;
    }

// cerrar conexión
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. En tu código estás usando `insert_id` que te devolvería el valor del último valor insertado, pero [deben cumplirse algunas condiciones, según el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php): *La función `mysqli_insert_id()` devuelve el ID generado por una consulta en una tabla con una columna que tenga el atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. **Si la última consulta no fue una sentencia `INSERT` o `UPDATE` o si la tabla modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT`, está función devolverá cero**.*

Answer (score 2):

Existe una función que hace eso por ti.

Con MySQLi

```
Por procedimiento
    $ultimoID = mysqli_insert_id($tuConexion);

Orientado a objetos
    $ultimoID = $tuConexion->insert_id;
```

Con PDO

```
PDO
    $ultimoID = $tuConexion->lastInsertId();
```

Saludos

Comment: Está usando ya en su código `insert_id`, pero dice que no le funciona. Conviene señalar que si la columna no es auto_increment esa *función* no *funciona*, valga la redundancia.

Answer (score 0):

Después de haber insertado el vehículo. Yo haría una consulta para saber el id del ultimo vehículo agregado. Algo como así.

```
$sql = "SELECT idVehiculo from vehiculos ORDER BY idVehiculo DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Esta consulta te regresara el `idVehiculo` del ultimo en la tabla(ultimo ingresado)

Por ejemplo:

Si en la tabla tienes:

idVehiculo | marca

```
    1       Audi

    2       Audi2
```

Si haces la consulta que te pase, te regresaria el numero 2 (`**idVehiculo = 2**`).

Cabe recalcar que en tu tabla de vehiculos el idVehiculo debe ser `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Para que cada idVehiculo sea diferente. (ya que los id son unicos).

Saludos.

Comment: por que debe ser `AUTO_INCREMENT` ?

Comment: la consulta que pusiste funciona incluso si el id no es `auto_increment`

Comment: Tienes razón, yo me refería al hecho de que los id's deben ser únicos.
Pero si, la consulta funciona sin que el campo sea AUTO_INCREMENT.